# Laravel belongsToMany.belongsTo nested relationship query where child column = parent id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many, belongs-to

I have two models (and database tables with Laravel naming conventions) and I am trying to Eager Load the `Collections` with `Equipment` and `Equipment.collection_meters` where `collection_meter` equals `Collection.id`.

**How can I access the `collections.id` in the child relationship `$query->with`?**

or

**How can I access the `equipment.pivot.collection_id` in the child relationship `$query->with`?**

Here are my models ...

```
class Collection extends Model {
    public function equipment() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Equipment::class, 'collection_equipment', 'collection_id', 'equipment_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}

class CollectionMeter extends Model {
    public function equipment() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Equipment::class); 
    }
}

class Equipment extends Model {
    public function collection_meters() {
        return $this->hasMany(CollectionMeter::class)->latest(); // ->currentStatus('active')
    }
}
```

**`equipment_id` column is in the `collection_meters` table**

Here is the code I have tried but I just can't seem to get the `Collection.id` in the child relationship query. If I leave out the child `$query->where`, I get **ALL** of the `equipment.equipment_meters`.

```
$collections = Collection::with([
    'equipment',
    'equipment.collection_meters' => function($query) {
        $query->where('collection_meters.collection_id', '=', 'collections.id');
    }
])
->get();
```

I have tried these in place of `'collections.id'` with the same result
`'equipment.pivot.collection_id'`
`'equipment.collection_id'`

**I do see this in the `[equipment] => Array`, can I access `[collection_id] => 2` in the `$query->where` somehow?**

```
[pivot] => Array
    (
        [collection_id] => 2
        [equipment_id] => 1
        [created_at] => 2019-09-17 00:17:00
        [updated_at] => 2019-09-17 00:17:00
    )
```

Results without the `$query->with`  (`[collection_meters]` has ALL)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Name of Collection
            [operator_id] => 1
            [location_id] => 4
            [account_id] => 1
            [date_time] => 2019-09-16 04:41:26
            [reconciliation_id] => 
            [created_by_id] => 1
            [updated_by_id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2019-09-16 23:44:43
            [updated_at] => 2019-09-18 17:32:53
            [equipment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => Name of Equipment
                            [ims_identifier] => AFA-64
                            [operator_identifier] => 073076-01
                            [equipment_model_id] => 1
                            [operator_id] => 1
                            [location_id] => 4
                            [created_by_id] => 1
                            [updated_by_id] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2019-07-17 13:17:28
                            [updated_at] => 2019-08-14 00:04:07
                            [pivot] => Array
                                (
                                    [collection_id] => 2
                                    [equipment_id] => 1
                                    [created_at] => 2019-09-17 00:17:00
                                    [updated_at] => 2019-09-17 00:17:00
                                )

                            [collection_meters] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 17
                                            [equipment_meter_id] => 1
                                            [value] => 0.25
                                            [gross] => 25.00
                                            [refund] => 2.00
                                            [test] => 2.00
                                            [reading_start] => 72985
                                            [reading_end] => 73085
                                            [collection_id] => 3
                                            [equipment_id] => 1
                                            [operator_id] => 1
                                            [location_id] => 4
                                            [account_id] => 1
                                            [created_by_id] => 1
                                            [updated_by_id] => 1
                                            [created_at] => 2019-09-17 18:23:41
                                            [updated_at] => 2019-09-17 22:56:50
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 9
                                            [equipment_meter_id] => 1
                                            [value] => 0.25
                                            [gross] => 24.00
                                            [refund] => 2.00
                                            [test] => 1.00
                                            [reading_start] => 72885
                                            [reading_end] => 72985
                                            [collection_id] => 2
                                            [equipment_id] => 1
                                            [operator_id] => 1
                                            [location_id] => 4
                                            [account_id] => 1
                                            [created_by_id] => 1
                                            [updated_by_id] => 1
                                            [created_at] => 2019-09-17 00:17:00
                                            [updated_at] => 2019-09-18 17:32:53
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1
                                            [equipment_meter_id] => 1
                                            [value] => 0.25
                                            [gross] => 282.50
                                            [refund] => 3.26
                                            [test] => 0.00
                                            [reading_start] => 71755
                                            [reading_end] => 72885
                                            [collection_id] => 1
                                            [equipment_id] => 1
                                            [operator_id] => 1
                                            [location_id] => 4
                                            [account_id] => 1
                                            [created_by_id] => 1
                                            [updated_by_id] => 1
                                            [created_at] => 2019-09-11 22:38:31
                                            [updated_at] => 2019-09-11 22:38:31
                                        )

                                )

                        )
```

Results with the `$query->with` (`[collection_meters]` is empty)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Name of Collection
            [operator_id] => 1
            [location_id] => 4
            [account_id] => 1
            [date_time] => 2019-09-16 04:41:26
            [reconciliation_id] => 
            [created_by_id] => 1
            [updated_by_id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2019-09-16 23:44:43
            [updated_at] => 2019-09-18 17:32:53
            [equipment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => Name of Equipment
                            [ims_identifier] => AFA-64
                            [operator_identifier] => 073076-01
                            [equipment_model_id] => 1
                            [operator_id] => 1
                            [location_id] => 4
                            [created_by_id] => 1
                            [updated_by_id] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2019-07-17 13:17:28
                            [updated_at] => 2019-08-14 00:04:07
                            [pivot] => Array
                                (
                                    [collection_id] => 2
                                    [equipment_id] => 1
                                    [created_at] => 2019-09-17 00:17:00
                                    [updated_at] => 2019-09-17 00:17:00
                                )

                            [collection_meters] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        ) ...
```

Results expected  (`[collection_meters]` has `[id] => 2` equals to `[collection_id] => 2`)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Name of Collection
            [operator_id] => 1
            [location_id] => 4
            [account_id] => 1
            [date_time] => 2019-09-16 04:41:26
            [reconciliation_id] => 
            [created_by_id] => 1
            [updated_by_id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2019-09-16 23:44:43
            [updated_at] => 2019-09-18 17:32:53
            [equipment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => Name of Equipment
                            [ims_identifier] => AFA-64
                            [operator_identifier] => 073076-01
                            [equipment_model_id] => 1
                            [operator_id] => 1
                            [location_id] => 4
                            [created_by_id] => 1
                            [updated_by_id] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2019-07-17 13:17:28
                            [updated_at] => 2019-08-14 00:04:07
                            [pivot] => Array
                                (
                                    [collection_id] => 2
                                    [equipment_id] => 1
                                    [created_at] => 2019-09-17 00:17:00
                                    [updated_at] => 2019-09-17 00:17:00
                                )

                            [collection_meters] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 9
                                            [equipment_meter_id] => 1
                                            [value] => 0.25
                                            [gross] => 24.00
                                            [refund] => 2.00
                                            [test] => 1.00
                                            [reading_start] => 72885
                                            [reading_end] => 72985
                                            [collection_id] => 2
                                            [equipment_id] => 1
                                            [operator_id] => 1
                                            [location_id] => 4
                                            [account_id] => 1
                                            [created_by_id] => 1
                                            [updated_by_id] => 1
                                            [created_at] => 2019-09-17 00:17:00
                                            [updated_at] => 2019-09-18 17:32:53
                                        )

                                )

                        )
```

Answer (score -1):

What kind of relationship are you using? "Many to Many" or "One to Many"? If you have three tables, one of them "pivot", you must define in both Models the relationship as belongsToMany:

```
class Collection extends Model {

    public function equipments() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Equipment::class, 'collection_equipment', 
        'collection_id', 'equipment_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

What is the name of the pivot table? collection_equipment ? How is your structure?

collections => collection_equipment <= equipments

```
class Equipment extends Model {

    public function collections() {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Collection::class, 'collection_equipment', 
       'equipment_id', 'collection_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Where is the collection_meters column? In the equipments table?

Then, if you want to get nested table information, just:

```
$collections = Collection::with('equipments')->get();
```

But sometimes you want to get information using a Pivot Model:

```
class CollectionEquipment extends Model {

    protected $table = 'collection_equipment';

    public function collection() {
       return $this->belongsTo(Collection::class, 'collection_id');
    }

    public function equipment() {
       return $this->belongsTo(Equipment::class, 'equipment_id');
    }

}
```

Then, just:

```
$collections = CollectionEquipment::with(['equipment', 'collection'])
               ->get();
```

Since you have already defined collection_id and equipment_id in all Model classes, you don't need to map them in your query as you would using 'join'

Comment: I have edited my question ... sorry, I forgot the `Equipment` relationship ...

`public function collection_meters() { return $this->hasMany(CollectionMeter::class)->latest();  }`

Comment: So, do you have a "one to many" relationship between equipment and CollectionMeter and another "one to many" relationship between collection and equipment? If so I will edit my answer

Comment: Yes, @alexandre-barbosa, that is exactly what I have ... `one to many` relationship between `equipment` and `CollectionMeter` and another `one to many` relationship between `collection` and `equipment`

Comment: You can see from my posted `Results` (toArray()'s) that I can get ALL of the `collection_meters` or NONE of the `collection_meters` just not the ONLY ONE that matches the `Collection.id` (root)

Comment: I need this somehow ... in the eager loaded scenario from above ... `WHERE collection_meters.equipment_id in (1, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16) AND collection_meters.collection_id = collections.id`